# Using to python to create a modified txt file

Tags: python

I am wondering to how to modify a text file. Suppose I have .txt like

```
1, yes, cool being
how, are you doing
see, you, you see them
```

I want  to create a new/modified file where the new file that looks like

```
1
yes, cool being

how
are you doing 

see
you, you see them
```

I have tried the following code

```
wordlist = []
with open('scores.txt') as f:
    wordlist = [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
    print(wordlist[0]) # trying to see if the output was the way i wanted
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('scores.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        splited = line.split(', ') # Split
        first_word = splited[0]
        others = ', '.join(splited[1:]) # Put them back
        print (first_word)
        print (others)
        print () # Empty line
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to `split` on the fist occurence of `,` and merge with a newline (`\n`) and overall merge the "paragraphs" with a newline again.

```
wordlist = []
with open('scores.txt', 'r+') as f:
    origlist = ['\n'.join(line.split(',', 1)) for line in f]

    wordlist.append('\n'.join(origlist))
    print(wordlist[0])
    f.write(wordlist[0])  # write back to scores.txt file
```

produces

```
'1\n yes, cool being\n\nhow\n are you doing\n\nsee\n you, you see them'
```

(This solution proposal does not append newlines at the end of the string as requested by you. If you are running windows, replace `\n` with `\r\n` and on MAC replace with `\r`.)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
file_in = open("input.txt","r")
file_out = open("output.txt","a")
line = file_in.readline()
while(line):
    file_out.write(line[0:line.index(',')]+"\n"+line[line.index(',')+1::]+"\n\n")
    line=file_in.readline()
file_in.close()
file_out.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with some gimmicks:

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as fin, open('mod_scores.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        try:
            first, rest = line.split(',', 1)
            fout.write(f"{first}\n{rest.strip()}\n\n")
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Found a line that has no separator:\n{line}")
```

1. this makes use of two open statements in one context manager, which has the advantage that both files will be closed automatically if processing has finished or an error occurs (thanks to Luciano Ramalho: Fluent Python).
2. looping over the lines of the input file like this uses the generator concept, i.e. you only need to keep one line in memory at any time and don't risk to run out of memory for very large files.
3. the try - except block captures any problematic lines in your input file. For example, when testing, I had added an empty line at the bottom. Split() then raises a ValueError, and this is what is captured here. Here, the error handling consists of a simple print statement, but of course you can do all kinds of other things instead.
4. the code uses "f strings" (available since Python 3.6 if I am not mistaken): they provide concise and also efficient text formatting. Note the rest.strip() within the {} term: this ensures that you don't have a blank character at the beginning of the next line.